# stop bouncing markers after all markers load

Tags: jquery, google-maps, animation, google-maps-markers

I have markers loading one at a time each sec. There are like 50 of them and it takes a while to load all of those. So as an indication that they are still loading, I have set their animation to bounce. But once they are all loaded, i want to stop the bouncing animation. How do i do that??

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var addresses = new Array();
var infowindow;
var theInterval;

function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.095287, -79.3185139);
    var myOptions = {
        maxZoom: 14,
        zoom: 9,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    getAddresses();
    theInterval = setInterval("codeAddress()", 1000);
});

function getAddresses () {
    $('.LocationAddress').each(function () {
        addresses.push($(this).text());
    });
}

function codeAddress() {
    if (addresses.length == 0) {
        clearInterval(theInterval);
    }
    var addy = addresses.pop();
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': addy
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                map: map,
                title: addy,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,

            });

            //Adding a click event to the marker 
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                infowindow.setContent('<div id=\"infowindow\" style=" height:100px;>' + '<div id=\"LeftInfo\">' + "Hello World!" + '</div>' + '</div>');
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
        }

    }); //Geocoder END
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep a list of all markers.

When everything loaded, loop though and stop their animation.

In other news, this: http://econym.org.uk/gmap/geomulti.htm is worth a read. Its old - and refers to v2 of hte API, otherwise the information is still relevent.

You also have a off-by-one error. The clearInterval should be called after the pop. Your current setup, still call the function one more time - even though the array is empty.